# Kubernetes Scheduler Extenders - when are they invoked?

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

From K8s v1.18, we have the scheduling context split into the scheduling cycle and the binding cycle with multiple extension points.

I have a question about the scheduler extenders in this context. Are they invoked after the scheduling cycle and before the binding cycle?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are invoked as the last step for scheduling decisions and it picks the pods that have a specific `schedulerName` in the pod spec. Number 3 [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/scheduling/scheduler_extender.md):

> (3) implementing a "scheduler extender" process that the standard Kubernetes scheduler calls out to as a final pass when making scheduling decisions.

So if your scheduler's name is `my-scheduler`  a pod spec would look something like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  schedulerName: my-scheduler  
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

In the logs it would show like this:

```sh
$ kubectl describe pod test-pod
Name:         test-pod
...
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From               Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled              25s   my-scheduler    Successfully assigned test-pod to minikube
```